# My assembler doesn't seem to output 32-bit code

Tags: assembly, nasm

This is an example of the behavior I ran into.

When assembling the following program:

```
[BITS 32]

mov eax, 0x1234
```

Using:

```
nasm -f bin in.asm -o out.bin
```

I get the following binary output:

```
B8 34 12 00 00
```

B8 is opcode for 'move into eax' and it should take a 32-bit value and put it in there (i.e. should just be `B8 34 12`). But instead is putting an extra `00 00` as if it were a 64-bit value.

I don't know if this is an issue specific to NASM as I haven't tried another assemblers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused. You have 4 bytes. 4 bytes is 32 bits. Not 64 bits. That would be 8 bytes.

A pair of hex digits is one byte, which is why disassembly output groups things into pairs of hex digits.

Consider, as a counter example,

```
[BITS 64]

mov rax, 0xCAFEBABEDEADBEEF
```

Which can be assembled (and then dumped to hex) to produce

```
0000000 b848 beef dead babe cafe               
000000a
```

Comment: Also note that if you're not making a flat binary, you need to use `-felf64` or whatever, and that makes `[bits 64]` redundant.  `[bits 32]` would let you assemble 32-bit machine code into a 64-bit object file, but that's not usually useful.